# Sql Alchemy QueuePool limit overflow

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, zope, connection-timeout

I have a Sql Alchemy application that is returning TimeOut:

> TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached,
>   connection timed out, timeout 30

I read in a different post that this happens when I don't close the session but I don't know if this applies to my code:

I connect to the database in the init.py:

```
from .dbmodels import (
    DBSession,
    Base,    

engine = create_engine("mysql://" + loadConfigVar("user") + ":" + loadConfigVar("password") + "@" + loadConfigVar("host") + "/" + loadConfigVar("schema"))

#Sets the engine to the session and the Base model class
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
```

Then in another python file I'm gathering some data in two functions but using DBSession that I initialized in init.py:

```
from .dbmodels import DBSession
from .dbmodels import resourcestatsModel

def getFeaturedGroups(max = 1):

    try:
        #Get the number of download per resource
        transaction.commit()
        rescount = DBSession.connection().execute("select resource_id,count(resource_id) as total FROM resourcestats")

        #Move the data to an array
        resources = []
        data = {}
        for row in rescount:
            data["resource_id"] = row.resource_id
            data["total"] = row.total
            resources.append(data)

        #Get the list of groups
        group_list = toolkit.get_action('group_list')({}, {})
        for group in group_list:
            #Get the details of each group
            group_info = toolkit.get_action('group_show')({}, {'id': group})
            #Count the features of the group
            addFesturedCount(resources,group,group_info)

        #Order the FeaturedGroups by total
        FeaturedGroups.sort(key=lambda x: x["total"],reverse=True)

        print FeaturedGroups
        #Move the data of the group to the result array.
        result = []
        count = 0
        for group in FeaturedGroups:
            group_info = toolkit.get_action('group_show')({}, {'id': group["group_id"]})
            result.append(group_info)
            count = count +1
            if count == max:
                break

        return result
    except:
        return []


    def getResourceStats(resourceID):
        transaction.commit()
        return  DBSession.query(resourcestatsModel).filter_by(resource_id = resourceID).count()
```

The session variables are created like this:

```
#Basic SQLAlchemy types
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Text,
    DateTime,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey
    )
# Use SQLAlchemy declarative type
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

#
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

#Use Zope' sqlalchemy  transaction manager
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

#Main plugin session
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

Because the session is created in the init.py and in subsequent code I just use it; at which point do I need to close the session? Or what else do I need to do to manage the pool size?

Comment: In the second code snippet, where is `transaction` defined?

Comment: Where is `getResourceStats` used? It looks like half the code is missing - can you add it all in or it may be impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Does this code work as-is? The `import` statement looks really strange, in addition to the issues mentioned by @TomDalton. At what point does the error occur? Is this the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? IOW, can you reduce this at all (or significantly) and still exhibit the same behavior? There seems to be a lot of business logic in there that is very unlikely the cause of the problem. Try removing it, and posting a full working (syntactically correct) example, and I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can manage pool size by adding parameters pool_size and max_overflow in function `create_engine`

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://" + loadConfigVar("user") + ":" + loadConfigVar("password") + "@" + loadConfigVar("host") + "/" + loadConfigVar("schema"), 
                        pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
```

Reference is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html)

You don't need to close the session, but the connection should be closed after your transaction has been done.
Replace:

```
rescount = DBSession.connection().execute("select resource_id,count(resource_id) as total FROM resourcestats")
```

By:

```
connection = DBSession.connection()
try:
    rescount = connection.execute("select resource_id,count(resource_id) as total FROM resourcestats")
    #do something
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Reference is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html)

Also, notice that mysql's connection that have been stale is closed after a particular period of time (this period can be configured in MySQL, I don't remember the default value), so you need passing pool_recycle value to your engine creation

Comment: Default timeout for inactive sessions in MySQL is 8 hours for both interactive and non-interactive connections: 
[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
[2] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout

Comment: You mentioned we should close connection and not session.

But fastAPI example says we should close session. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency

Comment: Closing a session doesn't close the connection, but it does prevent the error. If you import `contextlib.closing`, then the code just needs to be `with closing(Session()) as session: # do stuff`

Answer (score 7):

Add following method to your code. It will automatically close all unused/hanging connections and prevent bottleneck in your code. Especially if you are using following syntax Model.query.filter_by(attribute=var).first() and relationships / lazy loading.

```
   @app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db.session.remove()
```

Documentation on this is available here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/

Comment: Not request context?

Comment: I've tried this in our application and it doesn't fix the issue for us personally.

Comment: In case you use the Flask-SQLAlchemy module this is already configured, check [here](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/e5bf821072de0d55ff92891432004322864a7265/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L873).

Answer (score 1):

```
rescount = DBSession.connection().execute()
```

`rescount` is `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult'>` type.

You should call the `close()` func.